# How to Make Google Chrome Translate all Spanish Sites to English?

Tags: google-chrome, english

Google Chrome is not asking me for some reason if I want to translate spanish sites. AliExpress is working in Spanish wrongly, and I want to translate everything Spanish to English automatically.

---

How can you make Google Chrome Translate all Spanish sites to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a computer:

- Open Chrome on your computer.
- In the top-right corner, click the Menu.
- Click Settings > Show advanced settings.
- In the 'Languages' section, tick the box next to Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language that you read.
- Click Language and input settings. If Spanish isn't in the list, click add, select Spanish then tick 'Offer to translate pages in this language'. If Spanish is already in the list on the left under 'Languages' simply tick 'Offer to translate pages in this language'.

Chrome should now prompt you like before to translate pages in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

When I have tested this site the only parts that aren't translated are the images, translating images on the fly is almost impossible (if you know of a solution to this get a patent immediately and watch the money roll in!). Below is a screenshot of my Chrome translating the Spanish site to English.

[image: Non-translated bits]

There is a work-around, near the basket on the right you can choose to go to the global site which is all in English (even the images). I have highlight this option below.

[image: Link to the English version]